# Text not adjusting to browser window

Tags: css

I've bee experimenting lately with a responsive container for image, text and two columns of lists and can't seem to be able to make the text adjust to the browser window when I re-size it. Let me know if you have any ideas of why this might be happening. Thank you!

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="content">
<img src="http://www.labyrinth.net.au/~toonist/flash_goodies/graphics/image_sizes/rotate_circle_100.gif">
</div>

<div class="maintext">
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident deserunt architecto quasi quaerat cupiditate quis harum ipsum ipsa veritatis suscipit iure velit asperiores ipsam vitae reiciendis quos aliquam doloribus repellendus.</p>
<div class="linkleft">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier1">Left Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier2">Left Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier3">Left Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

  <div class="linkright">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier1">Right Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier2">Right Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier3">Right Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
p {
overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
width:650px
}

.content {
float:left;
margin:0 25px;
}

.maintext {
float:left;
padding-bottom: 25px;
width:500px;
}

.linkleft, .linkright {
display: block;
width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
.linkleft, .linkright {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;

    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
.maintext{
    background-color: tomato;
  }
}
```

Here's also the link to the pen: http://codepen.io/carlos_serrano/pen/jrcFu

Answer (score 0):

Fixing a "width" will force the div to remain that width unless otherwise stated.

Using

```
max-width: xyz
```

will allow it to expand to whatever value you like and then collapse to your min-width.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rhFcs

Comment: Thank you jBux. You see, my idea is for all elements to keep their position when the browser window is re-sized (except the lists, which should stack one on top of each other) I don't them to under the image for sizes < 480px.